# can't access std_srvs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlesim node offers a service called "/reset" that allows me to reset the position of the turtle. The type of message accepted by the "/reset" service is of type

```
std_srvs.Empty
```

I tried to do,

```
import std_srvs
from std_srvs.srv import Empty
```

but it didn't work. I kept getting error messages saying std_srvs couldn't be found. I then tried adding 'std_srvs' as one of the dependencies in the manifest file of the package. Now the node was able to access std_srvs but not 'Empty'. Finally I had to do,

```
roscp std_srvs Empty mypackage/srv
```

and then rosmake and finally it worked.

Could someone please tell me, why I wasn't able to access std_srv.Empty before copying it to the srv folder in my package?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28441/can%27t-access-std_srvs/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must include the following before importing any ROS packages:

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('package_name')
```

**EDIT**:

You must also have the packages that you want to use in your `manifest.xml`.

Here's an example... If your package is called "beginner_tutorials", you would put the following in your node:

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('beginner_tutorials')
```

If your node uses the `std_srvs` package, your `manifest.xml` file must contain the following line:

```
<depend package="std_srvs" />
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-24**:
I got those errors I mentioned earlier in spite of having that line which you have mentioned. But did you mean to say I should have had the line "import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('std_srvs')"? I don't suppose so..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i did try this:
atention for type Empty into msg and srv

---

for import msg

```
from std_msgs.msg import String, Float32, Empty
```

for import service - without problem Empty

```
import std_srvs.srv
```

publish message

```
take.publish(Empty())
```

call service

```
rospy.ServiceProxy('ardrone/flattrim', std_srvs.srv.Empty())
```

---

good luck!

---

Originally posted by [efrainra7](https://answers.ros.org/users/13846/efrainra7/) with karma: 11 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1